# scp -3 no longer works

Tags: scp

I am trying to transfer a large file between two remote hosts (both on different subnets). I found this command to work the first time:

```
scp -3 root@foo:/path/to/largefile user@bar:/path/to/where/it/should/go/
```

The command worked the first time, now when I attempt to run it again to transfer the other files, it never transfers. Instead I get a prompt for a password and then it exits with an exit code 1. Running `-v` gives me:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /run/sr-mount/3e3a905f-28ad-01b4-d50a-1ffe151ed28a/debian-8.8.0-amd64-CD-1.iso
Sending file modes: C0644 660602880 debian-8.8.0-amd64-CD-1.iso
Sink: C0644 660602880 debian-8.8.0-amd64-CD-1.iso
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2480, received 2372 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 32882.6, received 31450.6
debug1: Exit status 1
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2904, received 2964 bytes, in 3.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 893.5, received 912.0
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Can someone tell me why all of a sudden this command no longer works? I checked `/var/log/syslog` and couldn't find anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-vvv` to get more information from the log. But problem with `-3` is that you can not reasonably get any debug information about the errors from the remote sides ([upstream bug with patch](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2338)). The err messages are being send from one remove side to the other and there is no place to display them (without introducing some complexity).

To get an idea what could go wrong is probably easiest to make sure that the source file is properly readable (and there is no typo in the name) and the target folder is writable, there is enough of disk space and so on:

```
ssh root@foo stat /path/to/largefile
ssh user@bar stat /path/to/where/it/should/go/
```

Other possibility is to build OpenSSH from source and apply the above linked patch. It should print the errors in the client (It should be enough to do that only on your machine).

Or just use `rsync`, which is more suitable for performance, throughput and usability.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide an example of using rsync? I tried it before with flags -vuar, but it didnt work and mentioned it cannot transfer from remote server to remote server.

Comment: This answer is giving nice example how it can be done with `rsync` and port forwarding: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183504/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I cant get a tunnel going. Most likely because both servers are in different subnets... I guess I will have to scp the file to my local PC and then scp it again to the other server..