# Copy file from one remote server to another remote server

Tags: scp

I am at server A. I want to copy a file from remote server B to remote server C.

This can be done with below commands,

```
scp username@B:/path_of_file_on_server_B/file.txt /path_of_file_on_server_A
scp /path_of_file_on_server_A/file.txt username@C:/path_of_file_on_server_C
```

However I want to understand if there is any other way to directly copy file from remote server B to remote server C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rsync files between two remotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183504/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes)

Comment: @user1794469 but the OP here isn't using `rsync` and this is perfectly possible using `scp`.

Comment: @terdon OP tagged it as rsync, but yeah you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use remote paths as both source and target for `scp`:

```
scp username@B:/path_of_file_on_server_B/file.txt username@C:/path_of_file_on_server_C
```

Answer (score 0):

On centos it works with -3 option

```
scp -3 root@SERVERA:/imran.txt root@SERVERB:/
```

The -3 option instructs the scp command to route traffic through the issuing machine (From where we executing this command)

Comment: there is NO -3 parameter!