# Copying files from Ubuntu Server to WSL Bash Directory

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Can't find any other solutions hence this question. I am running Ubuntu Server (20) on my Raspberry Pi which I SSH'd into via WSL Bash on Windows 10. How do I copy a text file from Raspberry Pi to my local WSL bash directory running on my PC?

[image]

`scp ubuntu@192.168.0.20:/home/ubuntu/hello.txt noel@Noel-PC:/home`

I've tried [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518877/copy-file-from-one-remote-server-to-another-remote-server), and other SCP suggestions on how to transfer files from ServerA to ServerB but all I get is a blinking cursor for ages even though its just an empty text file to be transferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you use `scp`, you want to specify one remote location and one local path.  In this case, it looks like you're specifying two remote locations, which is probably not what you wanted to do.  If you want to refer to the local system, just use a plain path, not the `user@host:path` syntax.

If the Raspberry Pi is 192.168.0.20, then to copy to your local `/home` directory, you'd type this:

```
$ scp ubuntu@192.168.0.20:/home/ubuntu/hello.txt /home
```