# How to use rsync to copy files between 2 remote servers based on the localhost server?

Tags: ssh, rsync, ftp, file-copy

I have a case when I need to move data from an old server: **host1** to a new server: **host2**.
**The problem is host1 cannot see host2**, but I can use another server (**localhost**) to SSH to both host1 and host2.

Imagine it should work like this: **host1 -> localhost -> host2**

How can I use rsync to copy files between host1 and host2? I tried this command on localhost server but it says **The source and destination cannot both be remote.**

```
 rsync -avz host1:/workspace host2:/rasv1/old_code-de
```

Comment: You could try `scp -3 host1 host2`. The option `-3` means: "Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host."

Comment: I did not find `-3` option, as suggested by eblock, in mine rsync, nor in man pages on the internet (https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). Look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183504/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes

Comment: @nobody You will notice that eblock does not mention `rsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/312074/eblock

with

```
scp -3 host1 host2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tunneling to redirect the rsync using ssh.

Start logged as user@host1, and create the tunnel to host2 through your "localhost" (Let's call it "your_host" to avoid confusion):

```
ssh <your_host_user>@<your_host> -L 8080:<host2_ip>:22
```

Keep that terminal open, then on another terminal from host1 type:

```
rsync -avzh -e "ssh -p 8080" <source_file> <host2_user>@127.0.0.1:/<target_folder>
```

Of course you can use any other port instead of 8080.
As for using other method not involving ssh, I think it's possible but I didn't test.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware rsync does not support copying from remote server to remote server.

If you only need simple file copy you could just use `scp` with `-3` option as pointed out by @eblock

If you need rsync you could mount both servers to local folder with `sshfs`

```
sshfs user@server1:/path/on/server1 /local/path1
sshfs user@server2:/path/on/server2 /local/path2
```

And than copy files between local folders:

```
rsync -av /local/path1 /local/path2
```

To unmount:

```
fusermount -u /local/path1
fusermount -u /local/path2
```

Though i'm not sure about the speed/performance of `sshfs`.

Comment: Using `rsync` on top of `sshfs` is a really bad idea (it disables most of its optimisations)