# how to backup remote location containing hard links, without rsync

Tags: rsync, backup, sshfs, borgbackup

I want to backup `backintime`-data from an internet-facing, remote machine running debian 11 (src). That is the hardlinks-part from the title.
I want to back it up to a (very dumb) NAS (dest) in the internal network.

Connecting to both via ssh-keys and running the backup is a third machine running debian 10.

I'd like to use `borgbackup` - to stay with one solution for the all the machines (also: compression, encryption), but I'm open for other ideas.
For accessing remote data in `borgbackup`, use of `sshfs` is suggested in [their docs](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.16/usage/create.html#examples). But `sshfs` can't handle hardlinks on the reading side.

`Rsync` should be/is able to handle hardlinks but can only handle one remote connection.

Using `sshfs` on the dest-part of rsync throws errors ( rsync: chown "dest/filename" failed: No such file or directory (2) and rsync: mknod "dest/filename" failed: Operation not permitted (1)). The sshfs-option `-o sshfs_sync` is used.

So I thought piping `rsync` into `borgbackup` via the `stdin` option, but -again according to [borgbackup docs](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.16/usage/create.html#reading-from-stdin)- this omits metadata (seemingly even group-/ownership) from the file.

I still have to play with this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183516/134408

So, what could I do? What are my other options?